# How to Configure Path Params in xacml policies

Tags: java, wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create **XACML policy** by referring [wso2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Writing+XACML+policies+in+WSO2+Identity+Server+-+3). But what i actually need is, to check a url like this,

http://localhost:8280/services/Customers/getCustomers/{id}.json

Here id will be change for all request( is a path param value ). How can i write a policy and request for this requirement.

Comment: Me also looking this

Comment: http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/02/how-write-xacml-policies-1/

Comment: Is it possible to give exact template for resources rather than http://localhost:8280/services/Customers//* , like this http://localhost:8280/services/Customers/getCustomers/{id}.json